# java.net.UnknownHostException: "localhost": Name or service not known

Tags: java, redis, hosts, jedis

I'm trying to connect to Redis in Java using Jedis. I'm doing this simply like

```java
return new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig,
                    redisData.get("address").toString(),
                    redisData.get("port").asInt(),
                    2000,
                    redisData.get("password").toString());
```

With `{"address": "localhost", "port": 6363, "password": "password}`

However, I am getting this error when trying to connect:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed to create socket.
    at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:116)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:180)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.initializeFromClientConfig(Connection.java:338)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:53)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.<init>(Jedis.java:212)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:181)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:571)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:298)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:223)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:34)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:364)
    at org.myapp.monitors.Monitor$DefaultImpls.setRedis(Monitor.kt:13)
    at org.myapp.monitors.IntMonitor.setRedis(IntMonitor.kt:8)
    at org.myapp.monitors.IntMonitor.<init>(IntMonitor.kt:10)
    at org.myapp.monitors.IntMonitor.<init>(IntMonitor.kt:8)
    at org.myapp.monitors.MonitorFactory.makeMonitor(MonitorFactory.kt:22)
    at org.myapp.utils.ConfigUtils.getMonitors(ConfigUtils.java:62)
    at org.myapp.tp.TelPub.<clinit>(TelPub.kt:16)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: "localhost": Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:932)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1517)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:851)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300)
    at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.connectToFirstSuccessfulHost(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:58)
    at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:87)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: "localhost"
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:800)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300)
    at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.connectToFirstSuccessfulHost(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:58)
    at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:87)
    ... 17 more
```

Same thing happens if I replace `"localhost"` with `"127.0.0.1"` or `"::1"`.

I'm on popOS 21.10 and this is my `/etc/host` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost
127.0.1.1   pop-os.localdomain  pop-os
```

`echo $HOST_NAME` returns "thinkpad-t440p".

I've tried

```
127.0.0.1   thinkpad-t440p localhost
::1         localhost
127.0.1.1   pop-os.localdomain  pop-os
```

but same issue.

`ping localhost` gives me

```
PING localhost(localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
```

`ping thinkpad-t440p` gives me

```
PING thinkpad-t440p (192.168.0.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from thinkpad-t440p (192.168.0.42): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
```

Comment: `/etc/hosts` (not `/etc/host`). Also, try `ping 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes indeed. `PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms`

Comment: Any chance you're running some network blocking software? (Firewall, antivirus, etc.) It might block your incoming connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using the `toString()` method, which basically puts a string inside a string so it adds extra quotes to it or something.

Need to use `asString()` instead.